# Выяснить, что выполняют js скрипты на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть [сайт](http://www.gavlakgallery.com/) на котором стоит запрет правой кнопки мыши и на котором недоступно для просмотра содержимое страницы, только через консоль.

Хотел поинтересоваться что за загодочные скрипты на нем используются ниже и а также, что означает `data-email-protected`, хотя на странице нет формы обратной связи.

Ну и для чего подключается `jquery` таким образом.

```html
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\'/bundles/collagefrontend/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js\'><\/script>');
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var langInUrl = false;
    var closeText = "Close";
    var zoomText = "Zoom";
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('body>#supersized, body>#supersized-loader').remove();
    });
    var frontendParams = {
      currentScreen: null,
    };
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").append('<div id="supersized-loader"></div><ul id="supersized"></ul>');
    });
    var images = [{
      "image": "https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/files.collageplatform.com.prod\/image_cache\/supersized_big\/5374f947a9aa2c98748b4568\/03fc6f113a1e8bda6fd8c8fdb3af6505.jpeg",
      "title": "<h1><\/h1><h2><\/h2><h3><p><strong>&quot;Pastoral&quot;<\/strong><\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>Rob Wynne &amp; Francois-Xavier and Claude Lalanne at Gavlak Los Angeles<\/p>\r\n\r\n<p>September 15 - October 27, 2018<\/p><\/h3>",
      "alternate": null
    }];
    var altCss = [];
    var newsArtists = false;
    jsOptions.trigger.push({
      '_function': 'initSupersized',
      '_params': [images, altCss, newsArtists]
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body data-email-protected="" data-section-key="homepage" data-section-id="5374e8f7a9aa2c35708b4581" class="s-homepage">
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="email-protected-header">
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="email-protected-description">
</body>
```

Comment: там работает правая копка. Кликните не по центру, а в стороне

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вы явно не весь код приложили, но по существу

```
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\'/bundles/collagefrontend/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js\'><\/script>');
```

Это такая подстраховка, выше загружается скрипт `jQuery` с `CDN`, но если по какой-то причине он не загрузился ( `CDN` упал ), загружается свой локальный `jQuery`. Проверка идет как раз по наличию объекта `jQuery` в глобальной области видимости

**UPD**

```
jsOptions.trigger.push({
  '_function': 'initSupersized',
  '_params': [images, altCss, newsArtists]
});
```

Этот код запускает инициализацию библиотеки https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized

Comment: спасибо, но больше интересуют эти: `    var langInUrl = false;
    var closeText = "Close";
    var zoomText = "Zoom";` не вижу, чтобы эти переменные где-либо использовались и вот это
`$(document).ready(function() {
      $("body").append('<div id="supersized-loader"></div><ul id="supersized"></ul>');
    });` - загрузчик лоудера?